# How to get rid of padding/margin below an Antd Select?

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

Would anyone know how to zero out the padding or margin at the bottom of an Antd Select? It seems other Antd UI components default to zero. I've highlighted the container's border to show this.

```
<div style={{border: '1px solid red'>
        <Select ... style={{width: '100%', margin: '0px', padding: '0px'}} >
          <Option value={true}>A</Option>
          <Option value={false}>B</Option>
        </Select>
</div>
```

I've tried in CSS without success.

[image]

Comment: Can you tell me your antd version, thx

Comment: I'm using     "antd": "^4.14.0",

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it with inspecting the select modal's classname from developer tools and giving styles to those classes in my globals.css or components.css. Classnames looks like this `.ant-select-single`